# Can the default `window.top` ever be invalid as a reference?

Tags: javascript, redirect, window, language-lawyer

I want to redirect the user to an external page and simultaneously break out of a frameset.

The outermost frameset is most likely within the same domain as the page doing the redirection, but there is the possibility that it will span domains. In development, the outermost frameset might not even exist at all. Ideally, I want to cover all those situations.

The innermost page (the one that has the breakout code) is going to be served over HTTPS. The target URL may be HTTP or HTTPS. It is acceptable for the redirection to fail (there is a fallback link "click here to continue" to cover for that scenario) but the redirection should work in the majority of cases. Particularly for the purposes of this question, I'd hate for it to be more browser-dependent than necessary.

The web application itself is ASP.NET.

Because of the framesets, I can't simply use a HTTP redirect.

**So far** I have this Javascript code, which is registered as a startup script from within a class subclassing [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), where `...` represents the redirection target URL:

```
((window.top == null) ? (window) : (window.top)).location = '...';
```

**What bothers me** is what MDN has to say about [window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.top) and [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent), respectively. *Particularly,* the documentation for window.parent spells out explicitly that

> If a window does not have a parent, its `parent` property is a reference to itself.

which means that I can assert `window.parent != null`. But there is nothing similar about the value of `window.top`.

For the purposes of my question, you can assume that neither of these have been reassigned.

All that to lead up to the actual question: **Does `window.top` make guarantees similar to that of `window.parent`?** (I'm a bit concerned about the conditional expression. In my so far limited testing it works, but that doesn't prove it *correct.*)

As far as I can tell, at least MDN doesn't say for certain either way.

Comment: Note that you can re-assign all global variables in JavaScript. That means you can very well destroy `window` or `window.top` by assigning something else onto that variable.

Comment: @JimAho Good point about reassignment, thank you. In this case that's not a concern; I have edited to include that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML5 spec defines [`window.top`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#dom-top) like so:

> The top IDL attribute on the Window object of a Document in a browsing context b must return the WindowProxy object of its top-level browsing context (which would be its own WindowProxy object if it was a top-level browsing context itself), if it has one, or its own WindowProxy object otherwise (e.g. if it was a detached nested browsing context).

So the `top` attribute must always refer to a window. The spec also defines `top` as `readonly` so it is not posisble to change it to point to something else (if the spec is implemented properly).

Something is very bad if `window.top == null`!

Comment: The `readonly` modifier in IDL only means the property lacks an exposed _setter_ - it doesn't mean that the property is _immutable_; it just means that user code (i.e. a browser `<script>` cannot set or re-assign the property).

Answer (score 1):

At some point [since 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27249479/159145), [the HTML specification's definition of `window.top`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#dom-top) was refined to explicitly state that `window.top` **can** be `null` when the `Window` object *is not navigable*, which happens when  the *browsing context* of a `Window` (or `WindowProxy`) is *nulled out*:

> The `top` getter steps are:
>
> 1. If `this`'s <sub>(i.e. the `Window`'s)</sub> [navigable](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#window-navigable)<sub>([see also](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/document-sequences.html#navigable))</sub> is `null`, then return `null`.
> 2. Return this's navigable's top-level traversable's active WindowProxy.

*i.e.*: when your script has a valid (non-`null`, non-`undefined`) reference to a `Window` object, but the real-life browser window no-longer exists, then `.top` (and `.parent`, etc) will return `null`.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<iframe></iframe>

<script>
"use strict";
const element = document.querySelector("iframe");
const iframeWindow = element.contentWindow;
element.remove();

console.assert(iframeWindow.top === null);
console.assert(iframeWindow.parent === null);
console.assert(iframeWindow.frameElement === null);
</script>
```

It's reproducible here in a StackOverflow snippet:

(I needed to comment-out the `.frameElement` access as that violates StackOverflow's CSP).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<iframe></iframe>

<script>
"use strict";
const element = document.querySelector("iframe");
const iframeWindow = element.contentWindow;
element.remove();

console.assert(iframeWindow.top === null);
console.assert(iframeWindow.parent === null);
//console.assert(iframeWindow.frameElement === null);
</script>
```